# The microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0 provider is not registered

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, ms-access-2010

I have created a class library which will access Provider 4.0 Access database as separate solution. And also i have used in created DLL in the another project which accessed gives provider 4.0 error.

Steps :

1. Using 64 bit windows 8.0 machine.
2. Installed the driver for [64 bit OLEDB Provider 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13255).
3. Build DB class library in X64 and download the DLL.
4. Created Excel - Addin project (2013) which i have used DB library which i have created separately. Run using X64/ Any CPU configuration still facing the error.

Answer (score 2):

The download link in your question is for the Access Database Engine (a.k.a. "ACE"), whose Provider name is

```
Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0
```

not

```
Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0
```

**Edit re: comment**

If you really want to use the older "Jet" OLEDB provider:

You will have to ensure that your application runs as 32-bit because there is no 64-bit version of Jet. In your case, since you are creating an Excel add-in, you will have to build the DLL for "x86" (not "Any CPU") and require your users to run the 32-bit version of Excel.

Comment: Then any way to access 4.0 Provider DB.

Comment: One more doubt the setup which we are creating in 32 bit Excel addin can work in 64 bit excel also?